# I need some help in removing these errors

Tags: android

I am using navigation drawer, every time I clicked the drawer, it shows these errors in logcat everything is working functionally.

[image: errors]

I know the system couldn't find those files, but I just don't want to use any sounds when user clicking or touching the drawer..
please help me, thank you!

Comment: You can use a filter to just see your log output from your application.

Comment: These errors can be ignored since they're not from your application, they're from another application. Just filter them so they don't show in your LogCat.

Comment: @dutt oh I guessed there was another way to resolve that... thank you anyway!

Comment: @m0skit0 yup I am just gonna filter those errors, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Error is there, but it doesnt stop your application. It wont affect your application, so dont worry about it.